# case statement in Dax

Tags: dax

I have the following case when statement:

```
case when ts.wgt_kg / ((hgt_cm / 100) * (hgt_cm / 100)) < 18.5 then 'Underweight < 18.5'
when ts.wgt_kg / ((hgt_cm / 100) * (hgt_cm / 100)) between 18.5 and 24.9 then 'Normal 18.5-24.9'
when ts.wgt_kg / ((hgt_cm / 100) * (hgt_cm / 100)) between 25.0 and 29.9 then 'Overweight 25-29.9'
when ts.wgt_kg / ((hgt_cm / 100) * (hgt_cm / 100)) > 30.0 then 'Obese > 30.0'
end as BMI
```

How can i convert it into DAX? I tried to google it but I wasn't able to find anything useful. Can someone help me with that please. 
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using a `SWITCH` function.

Answer (score 3):

Try something along these lines:

```
BMI Category =
VAR BMI = ts.wgt_kg / ( ( hgt_cm / 100 ) * ( hgt_cm / 100 ) )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        BMI < 18.5, "Underweight < 18.5",
        BMI < 25.0, "Normal 18.5-24.9",
        BMI < 30.0, "Overweight 25-29.9",
        "Obese > 30.0"
    )
```

This will return the first condition that evaluates to true or use the last argument if none of the above are true.

Comment: What is the purpose of the true() expression?

Comment: @whytheq To make it return first true condition since SWITCH has to have an exact match. More detail: https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/

Comment: @AlexisOlson good contribution, very important to use the variable otherwise the operation would be extremely inefficient since the calculation would be performed each time for every comparison.