# Categorize number of meetings PowerBI

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, measure

So I created the following Measures:

First, I created this because I couldn't get VAR in the 2nd measure to pick it up from Table1.

```
Meetings in the Past 90 Days =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( table1[MEETING_HOSTED_PAST_90DAYS] ) )
```

Second, i created:

```
mtgs Category =
VAR mtgs = [Meetings in the Past 90 Days]
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        mtgs = BLANK (), "0 Mtgs Past 90 Days",
        mtgs >= 1 && mtgs <= 100, "1-100 Mtgs Past 90 Days",
        mtgs >= 101 && mtgs <= 500, "101-500 Mtgs Past 90 Days",
        "500+ Mtgs Past 90 Days"
    )
```

but I also have another column called Account Manager. and when I filter on account manager it will not show me the just the filter but all the sites in the table below.

[image: r]

Comment: I'd recommend a `SWITCH` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834964

Comment: @AlexisOlson thank you. the formula worked but if i filter in the table by Site_URL the filter wont work. it will still show everything

Comment: Can you show what you mean? (Edit the post to show what you've tried and how it's not working.)

Comment: @AlexisOlson Updated the notes. i recreated with the simplified version and it works. i think the issue is because i am connected to a dataset thanks for your help